# Did over half of the women who had abortions in Canada do so because they were pressured to?

Tags: canada, abortion

I came across an [Abortion Awareness clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIy7sWZUQVI&t=2m31s) that stated:

> Studies have shown that over half of post-abortive women in Canada say that their decision was heavily pressured and in some cases bullied by boyfriends, parents, and other authority figures. Most say they would have kept their baby if they simply had had more support.

I could not find any references to the studies mentioned in the video description. Are there any studies that verify or refute this claim?

Comment: I would ask the questions about which studies they are referring to as they do not appear to be listed in the video so there is nothing to back up what they are stating.

Comment: The quoted claim is really easy to validate, so much so that it could be non-notable: "Studies have shown that [some % of survey or interview respondents] say that [X]".  This is not the finding of a quantitative study but of as few as 2 or 3 studies with as few as 30 subjects each.  This claim could be perfectly true with just 60 subjects and 31 subjects saying "yes", since that's enough to use statistics on the numbers instead of the T-distribution.

Answer (score 11):

This is not specific to Canada, but according to [Women Who Suffered Emotionally from Abortion:
A Qualitative Synthesis of Their Experiences](http://www.jpands.org/vol22no4/coleman.pdf) *Journal of American Physicians and Surgeons* Volume 22 Number 4 Winter 2017:

> 58.3% of the women reported aborting to make
>   others happy
>
> 73.8% disagreed that their decision to abort
>   was entirely free from even subtle pressure from others to
>   abort

However, this is not based upon a random sample of people who had abortions.

Another study, [Induced abortion and traumatic stress: A preliminary
comparison of American and Russian women](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/15448616/) *Med Sci Monit*, 2004; 10(10): SR5-16, says 64% of American women, but only 37% of Russian women, felt pressured to abort.

Comment: The second link is broken, at least for me. [This](https://www.medscimonit.com/abstract/index/idArt/11784/act/3) appears to be the article to which you were referring.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks, how’s this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/15448616/ should be fixed now

Comment: That works, quite nicely. However ... The first link uses "even subtle pressure" as opposed to the "heavily pressured and in some cases bullied" in the question, and the second link does not qualify the level of pressure, or even if that was the dominant reason.

Comment: @DavidHammen right, I’m just giving 2 references on the topic, not saying the OP claim is true

Comment: "73.8% disagreed that their decision to abort was entirely free from even subtle pressure from others to abort" is a meaningless statistic. I'm surprised it's not 100%. I'd also be surprised if a similar proportion (or higher) weren't "entirely free from even subtle pressure" to keep the baby. "Subtle pressure" encompasses people telling you what they think, and I find it hard to believe that anyone contemplating abortion doesn't have both friends/family who think they should abort and those who don't.

Comment: An online survey may not be the best method to get to the actual data. Abortion is a difficult and potentially traumatic decision and citing "external pressure" can help rationalizing this to yourself.

Comment: @DavePhD I read through the study that you quoted, and there are significant issues with the [primary author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priscilla_K._Coleman).  The respondent section is a whole bunch of anti abortion propaganda where apparently the only benefit to abortion is to teach other women to not get abortions.  It's very possible this is where the video got the data from, but I agree that is not very scientific and I would be hesitant to trust anything gleamed from it.

Comment: @DenisS even she says the study is just “qualitative”. I voted for the other answer which says 20% decide based on what parent, husband or partner wants (down from 32% in 1987).

Comment: @DavePhD right, and I upvoted your answer because this is a very strong possibility for where the video got its source from.  I'm not going to think this is a bad answer just because the "study" they may be using is horrifically flawed and designed to create an outcome.

Comment: @DenisS and the study from the other answer is from a spin-off (Guttmacher Institute) of Planned Parenthood, which obviously has a pro-abortion bias.  It's difficult to find a neutral source.

Comment: *However, this is not based upon a random sample of people who had abortions.* - that is a bit of understatement. Participants were recruited from those who had post-abortion counseling with the evangelical Christian anti-abortion origanization CareNet. Any numbers coming out of that study are completely meaningless.

Comment: @Tgr And 100% of the women questioned had post-abortion counselling, right?

Comment: @gnasher729 “the majority of the women who completed the survey had contacted a crisis pregnancy center inquiring about post-abortion services”

Answer (score 6):

[This article from 2005](https://www.guttmacher.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/journals/3711005.pdf) quantifies several dozen reasons why women choose abortion.  I selected the following, which seem to fit the claim:

```
From Table 2.  Percentage of women reporting that specified
reasons contributed to their decision to have an abortion.
Figures for 2004; N = 1,160 (selected)    

Can't leave job to take care of a baby                      21%
Not enough support from husband or father                   14%
Not sure about relationship                                 19%
Relationship or marriage may break up soon                  11%
Husband or partner is abusive to me or my children           2%
Don't want other people to know I had sex or got pregnant   25%
Husband or partner wants me to have an abortion             14%
Parents want me to have an abortion                          6%
Was a victim of rape                                         1%
```

Note that the answers are not mutually exclusive; the sum of the entire table is 744%, so each survey respondent selected (on average) 7 reasons.

> [Finer, Frohwitrth, Dauphinee, Singh, and Moore, Reasons US women have abortions: Qualitative and qualitative perspectives (2005), *Perspectives on Sexual and Reproductive Health, 38(2), 90-95.*](https://www.guttmacher.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/journals/3711005.pdf)
>
> [Also summarized by the *American Psychological Association Task Force on Mental Health and Abortion (2008)*, page 80](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Brenda_Major/publication/237530469_APA_Task_Force_on_Mental_Health_and_Abortion/links/00b7d52c1b8a074046000000/APA-Task-Force-on-Mental-Health-and-Abortion.pdf#page=80)

Comment: There were primary questions and sub-questions.  The sub-questions (those indented in the table) were only asked if the person said "yes" to the corresponding primary question.  There were about 3.6 primary reasons per person.

Comment: Although interesting, that study was on US women and this question specifically asks about Canada. Although in my (UK) perspective there are many cultural similarities between the US and Canada, I don't know whether I would expect differences when it comes to abortions.